# The build tools for Intel C++ Compiler 17.0 (Platform Toolset = 'Intel C++ Compiler 17.0') cannot be found

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

I have a C code (pretty old one) that I tried to run in VS17 and am getting this error:

```
The build tools for Intel C++ Compiler 17.0 (Platform Toolset = 'Intel C++ Compiler 17.0') cannot be found. To build using the Intel C++ Compiler 17.0 build tools, please install Intel C++ Compiler 17.0 build tools. Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".
```

I am not including the code as it is old and big. 
Can someone please suggest what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

It means your project configuration was done with an old version of Visual Studio.

I suggest you follow the VS suggestion: at the solution pane, right click on the project/solution and select 'retarget solution'. This will change your solution/project configuration to the current visual studio you use (2017).

As the project/solution files will be overwritten by the 'retarget' process, it worth copying the solution/project files (or even the entire solution 
 directory) before starting the 'retarget solution' process, so you can revert to the previous state for troubleshooting etc.

An example:
I'm want to build an old version of librdkafka, which was originally built with VS2010, and I want to use VS2017.
when looking at the solution explorer pane, you can see all projects has "(Visual Studio 2010)" title near them, at the left side of each project name.

[image]

Now I right click on the solution, and select 'Retarget solution':
[image]

At the dialog box, you get, click OK, and that's it.

Comment: can you please explain how to do that? I am unable so far

Comment: I've added some pictures and explanation to the answer